# JavaFX ImageView does not show Image in BorderLayout

Tags: java, multithreading, image, javafx

I've a BorderLayout containing View. At the left and right side there're two ImageViews. I am setting there image via a ObejctProperty from a another thread. TypedImage is just a Container for javaFXs Image.

```
@Override
public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends TypedImage> observable,
        TypedImage oldValue, 
        TypedImage newValue) {
    switch (newValue.getTyp()) {
    case TYPE1:
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                imageView1.setImage(newValue.getImage());
            }
        });
    case TYPE2:
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                imageView2.setImage(newValue.getImage());
            }
        });
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

The methode changed is normaly call twice, because the Listener is listening to two ObjectProperties. When the methode is call the first time the matching ImageView (depends on the type) is updated and is showing the Image in the UI. When the methode is called the second time its from the second property, for the second ImageView. From thsi point JUST the last updated ImageView is showing the Image within the UI, the first updated ImageView is invisible or empty.. Can anybody help me to understand and fix this?

**Java-Implementaion**

```
public class MainApp extends Application {
  private ObjectProperty<TypedImage> image1 = new SimpleObjectProperty<TypedImage>();
  private ObjectProperty<TypedImage> image2 = new SimpleObjectProperty<TypedImage>();

  public vois start(){
    [..]
    image1.addListener(mainView.getController());
    image2.addListener(mainView.getController());
    {
      Image1Drawer drawer = new Image1Drawer();
      drawer.setParent(this);
      Thread t = new Thread(drawer);
      t.start();
    }
    {
      Image2Drawer drawer = new Image2Drawer();
      drawer.setParent(this);
      Thread t = new Thread(drawer);
      t.start();
    }
    [..]
  }

  public void notifyDrawerFinish(AbstractDrawer source, TypedImage img){
    if(source instanceof Image1Drawer){ image1.setValue(img); }
    if(source instanceof Image2Drawer){ image2.setValue(img); }
  }
}

/**
  * extended by Image1Drawer and Image2Drawer, run-methode draws stuff on image
  */
public abstract class AbstractDrawer implements Runable {
  private MainApp parent;
  private void fireFinish(TypedImage img){
    mainApp.notifyDrawerFinish(this,img);
  }
  public void setParent(MainApp parent){ 
    this.parent = parent; 
  }
}

public class MianViewController implements Initializable, ChangeListener {
  @FXML
  private ImageView imageView1;
  @FXML
  private ImageView imageView2;

  [..]
  public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends TypedImage> observable,
        TypedImage oldValue, 
        TypedImage newValue) {
    /* see above */
  }
  [..]
}
```

**FXML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity"
    minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="600.0"
    prefWidth="800.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="org.nemo.view.MainViewController">>
    <left>
        <ImageView fx:id="imageView1" fitHeight="600.0" fitWidth="50.0"
            pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
    </left>
    <right>
        <ImageView fx:id="imageView2" fitHeight="600.0" fitWidth="50.0"
            pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
    </right>
</BorderPane>
```

Comment: Can you post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that I can have a better understanding of your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting controller's path in your FXML file. I think you are missing that:

```
<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity"
minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="600.0"
prefWidth="800.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME.MianViewController">
```

Comment: Soory i've forgot to copy this.. it has no effect